# Surface Integral directly

Tags: calculus, integration, surfaces

Surface integral that has me stumped.

Q: Calculate $\int \int_{S} F \cdot dA$

Where $F(x,y,z)= xi+yj+zk$ S is the boundary of the region $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq z \leq (2-x^{2}-y^{2})^{1/2}$ oriented so that the normal points out of the region.

Thx this is a good deal harder then the other recommended problems i have completed thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a standard "applying the divergence theorem" problem. Notice 
$$
\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{A} = \iiint_V \nabla\cdot  \mathbf{F}\, dV = 3\iiint_V\,dV
$$
The region
$$
x^{2}+y^{2} \leq z \leq (2-x^{2}-y^{2})^{1/2}
$$
which is the intersection of the paraboloid and a sphere looking like the following figure:
[image: surf_int]

Notice in this figure the region is artificially divided into two parts using a cone.

First part is below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2$, above the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, integral within the first part is easier to be integrated in spherical coordinates:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \in (0,\sqrt{2})
\\
&\phi = \arccos\frac{z}{r} \in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})
\\
&\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{x} \in (0,2\pi)
\end{aligned}
$$
this is a cone with a spherical top. The other part is below the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, above the paraboloid $z = x^2+y^2$. Integral within the second part is easier to be integrated in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in (0,1)
\\
&z \in (\rho^2,\rho)
\\
&\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{x} \in (0,2\pi)
\end{aligned}
$$
The integral becomes:
$$
\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{A} = 3\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 \int_0^\sqrt{2} r^2 \,dr d\phi d\theta + 3\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{1}_0 \int_{\rho^2}^\rho \rho \,dz d\rho  d\theta= \sqrt{2}\pi^2 + \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: @RonGordon The cone is used to divide the region into two parts, for easier change of variables.